# How to link a running job to spark transformation

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a list of all active job, in a spark job application.

```
sc.statusTracker.getActiveJobIds().foreach(jobId => { 
    val job: SparkJobInfo = sc.statusTracker.getJobInfo(jobId).get
    ...
})
```

I have a piece of code, doing some basic transformation and action.
For example:

```
val oldDf = dfInput.filter(age > 18)
val youngDf = dfInput.filter(age < 10)
oldDf.count()
youngDf.count()
```

How can I link between the jobId to appropriate transformation? How can I access the name of the running job?
My end goal is to get statistic about how many tasks from job #1 were completed, and I want to link job #1 to the *age > 18* filter transformation.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think it would be easier if you could query the [rest api](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#rest-api) that provides information to the ui?

Comment: @mkaran Actually it does not solve the problem, since from the code I can't relate to "count at line 22" which is the job name at the rest api. Can you think about a proper solution?

Comment: Hmm, yes indeed you cannot easily join job to code from the limited api. If you want something as fine-grained as this, I would definitely go about it differently, if you have access to the code being run because: [statusTracker information is not complete](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/status.py#L47)
and it doesn't seem to provide the level of info you need.
(e.g. I would be modifying the code and use a metrics lib like prometheus to gather info)

Comment: @mkaran Can you further explain what will you do? How can i use prometheus to get how many lines have been processed already (for example, it can be any transformation...)?

Comment: Which distribution are you using? HW or cloudera or mapR?

Comment: @Prazy The cloudera one / stand alone.

Comment: What do you mean by link?

Comment: You can access spark UI. Follow in here: https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-9-x/topics/operation_spark_applications.html **THIS IS SPARK UI** You can run the job and check out there.